# Filling a gridview with data from database

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a report screen with 6 textboxes. I check the checkboxes and look for data in a database with an SQL query. When I click on the button to generate the report, it doesn't show any data in the gridview. I just pasted the gridview from my toolbox to the screen and want to fill it with my C# code and SQL command. Am I missing something?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=SmmsData;Integrated Security=True");
    connect.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connect;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DrukSensor, FlowSensor, TempSensor, KwaliteitSensor, Toerental, OlieVerbruik"
        + " FROM SysteemSensorInfo"
        + " WHERE DrukSensor=@DrukSensor"
        + " AND FlowSensor=@FlowSensor"
        + " AND TempSensor=@TempSensor"
        + " AND KwaliteitSensor=@KwaliteitSensor"
        + " AND Toerental=@Toerental"
        + " AND Olieverbruik=@OlieVerbruik"
        ;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DrukSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FlowSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TempSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@KwaliteitSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Toerental", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OlieVerbruik", SqlDbType.Bit);

    cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@FlowSensor"].Value = CheckBoxFlow.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@TempSensor"].Value = CheckBoxTemp.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@KwaliteitSensor"].Value = CheckKwaliteit.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@Toerental"].Value = CheckBoxToerenTal.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@OlieVerbruik"].Value = CheckBoxOlieVerbruik.Checked;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not binded `data` to `gridview`. Bind data to gridview using `DataBind`

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. Now i also know that my query with checkbox checks isnt working!

Answer (score 0):

Use BindData to your gridview which bind all the data to your gridview

```js
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=SmmsData;Integrated Security=True");
    connect.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connect;
     sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DrukSensor, FlowSensor, TempSensor, KwaliteitSensor, Toerental, OlieVerbruik"
        + " FROM SysteemSensorInfo"
        + " WHERE DrukSensor=@DrukSensor"
        + " AND FlowSensor=@FlowSensor"
        + " AND TempSensor=@TempSensor"
        + " AND KwaliteitSensor=@KwaliteitSensor"
        + " AND Toerental=@Toerental"
        + " AND Olieverbruik=@OlieVerbruik"
        ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DrukSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FlowSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TempSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@KwaliteitSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Toerental", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OlieVerbruik", SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@FlowSensor"].Value = CheckBoxFlow.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@TempSensor"].Value = CheckBoxTemp.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@KwaliteitSensor"].Value = CheckKwaliteit.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@Toerental"].Value = CheckBoxToerenTal.Checked;
    cmd.Parameters["@OlieVerbruik"].Value = CheckBoxOlieVerbruik.Checked;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);.
    DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
    sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
    GridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;       
    GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
}
```